# Phonegap fileReader error message on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, filereader

I'm downloading a ZIP file containing 4 files, extracting them, and parsing the CSV data into SQL, and inserting it into an iOS app.

3 of the 4 files are processed fine, but one of them (about 17,000 rows of data, file size about 2MB) is failing. This is my readfile function, and the JSON output from a serialized error object, provided by the `failed` function

```
    readFile = function( fileEntry ) {
        fileEntry.file(
            function( fileObject ){ 
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function( evt ) {
                    parseFile( fileObject.name, evt.target.result );
                };    
                reader.onerror = failed;
                reader.readAsText( fileObject );
            }
        );
    }
```

Error object:

```
    {
        "type":"error",
        "bubbles":false,
        "cancelBubble":false,
        "cancelable":false,
        "lengthComputable":false,
        "loaded":0,
        "total":0,
        "target":{
            "_readyState":2,
            "_error":{"code":5},
            "_result":null,
            "_fileName":"/var/mobile/Applications/14323F76-D82C-4040-85AF-D37F2C73BE73/Documents/data/events.uk.data",
            "_realReader":{
                "readyState":0,
                "result":null,
                "onloadstart":null,
                "onabort":null,
                "error":null,
                "onprogress":null,
                "onloadend":null
            }
        }
    }
```

This error tells me which file is causing the problem, but there is no useful message, the only thing that looks like it might be useful is `_error: {code: 5}`.

**EDIT**

According to this URL:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError

The HTML File Error with a value 5 is this:

> ENCODING_ERR | 5 | The URL is malformed. Make sure that the URL is
>   complete and valid.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Or how to get better error information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I had a look through my source file (17000 lines of dollar sign separated data, as I couldn't use commas) and I had some rogue brackets (), exclamation marks ! and a pound sterling symbol £.

Removing those fixed the problem.

Which one of those would really be stopping the FileReader from reading - considering I'm using $ to separate my values?

Comment: I had the same problem again with a non-breaking space

Comment: where did you remove those characters, in the file path or in the files itself?